# Extjs one level up icons directory

Tags: javascript, extjs

We have an existing icons directory in c++ which we would like to use for our extjs application also.
As per our requirement, we want the icons directory outside of the Extjs App directory. So I referred to my icons like below.
Example of button config:

```
 { "id": "Open1", "icon": "./../COMMON/Resources/icons/T1Icon1.ico", "scale": "medium" }
```

But the icon is not visible in html.

In dev tools it shows as :

```
background-image: url("./../COMMON/Resources/icons/T1Icon1.ico");
```

On clicking on the link it goes to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5501/COMMON/Resources/icons/T1Icon1.ico
```

which is incorrect.

What mistake I'm doing? Console shows the image not found errors.
If I move the COMMON directory into the Extjs App directory then all icons are shown.

EDITED:

My directory structure

[image]

I'm a beginner in using Extjs framework and also Js/Css. Kindly excuse, If I could not provide the relavent information.

Comment: Can you show us how the link to your app looks like? For your example to work you would have to be at least `127.0.0.1:5501/resources/MyCSS.css` that way css can go up one level and find the COMMON folder. The folder has to be in your web-universe ;)

Comment: Please see my EDITED section. yes, the images folder is not in the web universe. But 'image' component works.

Answer (score 1):

Your server shows the base path:

```
// folder equivalent
127.0.0.1:5501/ === vejsui
// You start the app at
127.0.0.1:5501/index.html
```

If you start a local server you cannot go beyound the base path.
You would have to start your server at `ExtJS` in order to be able to go into `COMMON`.

That way you start the app with:

```
127.0.0.1:5501/vejsui/index.html
```